# get dates periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

it is necessary to get the date periods.
input data:

```
     login    date_start    date_end    code
    'user1', '2022-02-09', '2022-02-09'  DO
    'user1', '2022-02-10', '2022-02-10'  DO
    'user1', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-11'  DO
    'user1', '2022-03-28', '2022-03-28'  OT
    'user1', '2022-03-29', '2022-03-29'  OT
    'user1', '2022-03-30', '2022-03-30'  OT
    'user1', '2022-03-31', '2022-03-31'  OT
    'user1', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01'  OT
    'user1', '2022-04-04', '2022-04-04'  DO
```

expected result:

```
login  date_start  date_end   
user1  2022-02-09  2022-02-11 
user1  2022-03-28  2022-04-01
user1  2022-04-04  2022-04-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One trick we can use here is to create a pseudo-group which tracks to which island of continuous dates each record belongs.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(date_start, 1, date_start) OVER
                        (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY date_start) =
                        DATEADD(day, -1, date_start)
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY date_start) AS grp
    FROM cte
)

SELECT login, MIN(date_start) AS date_start, MAX(date_end) AS date_end
FROM cte2
GROUP BY login, grp
ORDER BY MIN(date_start);
```

### Demo

In the first CTE above, the alias `cnt` gets assigned to a value of 1 whenever the preceding date is *not* one day earlier than the current date.  We can then sum over this column and obtain groups of dates forming a continuous range.

Answer (score -2):

like this

`select  max(date_end) date_end ,  min(date_start) date_start,  login  from  table  group by  login, code`

Comment: When using `group by login` you will only end up with 1 record for `login`.   Expected result show 3 lines for `login`.   there seems to be missing something,.....

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: just add an group by column

Comment: Please test your _answer_ before posting, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=752612b7abf7a9312a6c18ce66f987ed) which shows the current SQL with an invalid output.